# ElasticSearch: obtaining individual scores from each query inside of a bool query

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

Assume I have a compound bool query with various "must" and "should" statements that each may include different leaf queries including "multi-match" and "match_phrase" queries such as below.

How can I get the score from individual queries packed into a single query?
I know one way could be to break it down into multiple queries, execute each, and then aggregate the results in code-level (not query-level). However, I suppose that is less efficient, plus, I lose sorting/pagination/.... features from ElasticSearch.

I think "Explanation API" is also not useful for me since it provides very low-level details of scoring (inefficient and hard to parse) while I just need to know the score for each specific leaf query (which I've also already named them)

If I'm wrong on any terminology (e.g. compound, leaf), please correct me. The big picture is how to obtain individual scores from each sub-query inside of a bool query.

PS: I came across [Different score functions in bool query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736999/different-score-functions-in-bool-query). However, it does not return the scores. If I wrap my queries in "function_score", I want the scoring to be default but obtain the individual scores in response to the query.

Please see the snippet below:

````
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "...",
            "fields": [
              "field1^3",
              "field2^5"
            ],
            "_name": "must1_mm",
            "boost": 3
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "...",
            "fields": [
              "field3^2",
              "field4^5"
            ],
            "boost": 2,
            "_name": "should1_mm",
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
          {
          "match_phrase": {
            "field5": {
              "_name": "phrase1",
              "boost": 1.5,
              "query": "..."
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "field6": {
              "_name": "phrase2",
              "boost": 1,
              "query": "..."
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Use search_type as dfs_query_then_fetch. Multiple shard cluster can result in incorrect score values across complete elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: 1. If I add this, do I get the individual scores from each subquery? 2. If I accept that amount of error, can I still get the individual scores without using dfs_query_then_fetch? (due to efficiency).