# ElasticSearch: given a document and a query, what is the relevance score?

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring, relevance

Once a query is executed on ElasticSearch, a relevance `_score` is calculated for each retrieved document.
Given a specific document (e.g. by doc ID) and a specific query, I would like to see what is its `_score`?

One way is perhaps to query ES, retrieve all the hit documents, and look up the desired document out of all the retrieved documents to see its score.

I assume there should be a more efficient way to do this. Given a query and a document ID, what is its `_score`?

I'm using ElasticSearch 7.x

PS: I need this for a learning-to-rank scenario (to create my judgment list). I have in fact a complex query that was created from various `should` and `must` over different fields. My major requirement was [to get the score value for each individual sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470667/elasticsearch-obtaining-individual-scores-from-each-query-inside-of-a-bool-quer), which seems there is no solution for it. I want to understand which part of this complex query is more useful and which one is less. The only way I've come up with is to execute each sub-query separately to get the score but I do not want to actually execute that query just asking for what is the score of a specific document for that sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoring of the document is not only related to just the document and all other documents in the index, but it also depends on various factor like:

1. `_score` is calculated per shard basis not on an index basis by default, although you can change this behavior by using `DFS Query Then Fetch` param in your query. More info on [this official blog](http://DFS%20Query%20Then%20Fetch).
2. Is there is any boost applied at index or query time([index time is deprecated from 5.X](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html)).
3. Any custom scoring function is used in addition to the default ES scoring algorithm([tf/idf in old versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)) and [BM25 in the latest versions.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-1-how-shards-affect-relevance-scoring-in-elasticsearch)

**Edit: Based on the comments from the other respected community members, rephrasing the below statement:**

To answer your question, Using the [_explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API, you can understand how Elasticsearch computes a score explanation for a query and a specific document. This can give useful feedback on whether a document matches or didn’t match a specific query.

Comment: Using _explain, can I count on explanation.value as a score value for that query+doc? Given a doc that would rank lower than another in actual search (querying time), would I get a lower value in explain? Then, that would work. Thanks :).

Comment: @mhn_namak, yes given a doc if it comes in your query result, then it would get lower value of `_score` in explain as well and you can try this API in both old and new version of ES to understand the diff b/w tf/idf and bm25, also if you give `DFS Query Then Fetch` and you have multiple shards then also same doc with same query will have different score and rank, also it mention the boosting part as well

Comment: @mhn_namak, so overall looks like it would work and reveal a lot of info you need :)

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja Explain API [does exactly what the person was asking for](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html#sample-api-desc) + the explanation how this value was computed. The answer makes an impression that this is not possible and is a hack, although it is not a hack.

Comment: _explain is the best path to answering questions like this, afaik.

Comment: Sure guys would update my answer tomorrow. It's late here and commenting from my mobile 

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica updated my answer, please go through it and let me know if further medication required

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev updated my answer, please go through it and let me know if further medication required

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev , thank you for suggesting and correcting me :), have a great day ahead